# Iterate over JS Object Elements and alter them

Tags: javascript

How can I get access to the value from the JS object to alter it inside the for loop?

```
var dataForModal = {gpsID: response.id, lastUpdated: response.lastUpdate};

$.each(dataForModal, function (index, value) {
        if(value === undefined) {
            //this will ofcourse just change the value of the local var value
            value="<i class='mNotAvailable'>not available</i>";
        }
});
```

Comment: just use `dataForModal`. its closed upon.

Comment: a property on `dataForModal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just assigning the new value to a variable in local scope, that wont affect the object at any means,

```
$.each(dataForModal, function (index, value) {
  if(value === undefined) {
    dataForModal[index] ="<i class='mNotAvailable'>not available</i>";
    //use dataForModal here and use the "index" to access the relevant key.
  }
});
```